# Extract part of URL

Tags: objective-c, url, extract, parameters

I have an URL and need to extract a part of it.

The url is like this:
`http://website.com/get.php?url=http://www.website2.com/index.html?articleID=123456`

And I need to extract this part:
`http://www.website2.com/index.html?articleID=123456`

How would I do this in Objective-C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, create a NSURL. Then, use the `query`method to get the query string part:

```
NSURL    * url = [ NSURL URLWithString: @"... your url ..." ];
NSString * q   = [ url query ];
```

Then you can use the NSString methods to isolate the needed part.

Comment: Thanks, now I get: url=http://www.website2.com/index.html?articleID=123456   How can I remove the "url=" ?

Comment: As NSResponder said, now you can use rangeOfSubstring and componentsSeparatedByString methods. Take a look at the documentation:  http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Answer (score 2):

See the `NSString` `-rangeOfSubstring:` and `-componentsSeparatedByString:` methods.

In this case, you could just split the string at the "=".