# Fetching part of URL from given URL

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extract part of URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308681/extract-part-of-url)

How can I fetch part of a url from whole url string?

Example given url:

```
http://example@url.com:7006/imageID = 45254
```

Required part:

```
http://example@url.com:7006
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work in the general case:

```
NSString* str = @"http://example@url.com:7006/imageID=45254";
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];    
NSString* aaa = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[url path] withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 3):

See the [NSURL Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) section on "Accessing Parts of a URL". You probably want something like `[-NSURL baseURL]` or `[-NSURL pathComponents]`.